# Why mmap /dev/mem return different address?

Tags: linux, mmap

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <errno.h>

long* mapmem(off_t offset)
{
    int fd;
    long *ret;

    fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR|O_SYNC);

    if (fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        return NULL;
    }

    printf("offset (pageaddr) is: %ld\n", offset);

    ret = mmap(0, sizeof(long), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, offset);
    if (ret == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        ret = NULL;
    }

    printf("Return address is: %p\n", ret);

    if (close(fd) == -1)
        perror("close");

    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long *mem = 0;
    volatile long *_mem = 0, dummy;
    long long int addr, offset, pageaddr;
    char *endpt;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s <addr>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    addr = strtoll(argv[1], &endpt, 16);
    offset = addr % sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
    pageaddr = addr - offset;

    printf("addr is: %lld, offset: %lld, pageaddr: %lld\n", addr, offset, pageaddr);

    mem = mapmem(pageaddr);

    return 0;
}
```

Why is the mmaped physical address different fro what we passed into? Or is the address returned virtual address that mapped to the corresponding physical address?

My output for running the above program:

```
 $ sudo ./test 0x12345
addr is: 74565, offset: 837, pageaddr: 73728
offset is: 73728
Return address is: 0x7f3081fc0000
```

Comment: `man mem: mem is a character device file that is an image of the main memory of the computer.` I guess it means that your program asks OS to map a physical address of the main memory to some address in a virtual space of your process.

Comment: Why do you believe that virtual addresses should be the same as physical addresses ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I just want to confirm that the address returned is in the virtual address space of my current running program, even if mapping from `/dev/mem`. I think this is the case. For normal address, I know it is in virtual address space.

Answer (score 1):

Mmap returns an address of a memory buffer you can access: as such, it is a virtual address, also because physical addresses are supposed not be visible to userspace. Indeed, current architectures always (but in the very early seconds of the boot process) run with memory virtualization enabled. You see physical addresses only inside the kernel, and only if you work with physical memory explicitly; but you never can access them directly, you first need to map them to virtual addresses.

What you see in your program is thus a virtual address, which differs from time to time. When you mmap, Linux chooses a free virtual memory area inside your process' virtual memory that is big enough to accomodate the mapping you are requesting, and maps the physical memory to that area. Which virtual memory area Linux selects depends on the availability and on other factors like Address space layout randomization (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization).